# Update an object - SOAP API /Selenium Java

Tags: soap-api, java, selenium

I've faced an issue. I'm trying to create a method to update a requirement in Salesforce. (I'm using Selenium - Java) and I have the following error. **" The method update(com.sforce.soap.enterprise.sobject.SObject[]) in the type EnterpriseConnection is not applicable for the arguments (com.sforce.async.SObject[]) Type mismatch: cannot convert from Requirement__c to SObject".**

```
 static EnterpriseConnection connection = GetConnection();

    private static EnterpriseConnection GetConnection()
    {
    String username = "aaa";
    String password = "aaa";
    String authEndPoint = "aaa";

    try
    {
    ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
    config.setUsername(username);
    config.setPassword(password);
    config.setAuthEndpoint(authEndPoint);

    return new EnterpriseConnection(config);
    }
    catch (ConnectionException ce)
    {
    ce.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
    }

    public static class forceLogin1
    {
          
    public boolean loginSample() {
           boolean success = false;
           String username = "aaa";
           String password = "aaa!";
           String authEndPoint = "aaa";
         
           try {
              ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
              config.setUsername(username);
              config.setPassword(password);        
         
              System.out.println("AuthEndPoint: " + authEndPoint);
              config.setAuthEndpoint(authEndPoint);
         
              EnterpriseConnection connection = new EnterpriseConnection(config);
         
            
              com.sforce.soap.enterprise.GetUserInfoResult userInfo = connection.getUserInfo();
              System.out.println("UserID: " + userInfo.getUserId());
              System.out.println("User Full Name: " + userInfo.getUserFullName());
              System.out.println("User Email: " + userInfo.getUserEmail());
              System.out.println();
              System.out.println("SessionID: " + config.getSessionId());
              System.out.println("Auth End Point: " + config.getAuthEndpoint());
              System.out
                    .println("Service End Point: " + config.getServiceEndpoint());
              System.out.println();
         
              success = true;
           } catch (ConnectionException ce) {
              ce.printStackTrace();
           }
         
           return success;
        }
    }
    
    public static void updateRequirements(String oppId) {
        
        try{  
        Requirement__c updateRequirement  = new Requirement__c();
    
           updateRequirement.setId(oppId);
           updateRequirement.setStatus__c("Pending");
           SaveResult[] results = connection
                    .update(new SObject[] { updateRequirement  });
           } 
    catch (ConnectionException ce) {
              ce.printStackTrace();
           }
        }
```

Imports:

```
import com.sforce.async.SObject;
import com.sforce.soap.enterprise.EnterpriseConnection;
import com.sforce.soap.enterprise.SaveResult;
import com.sforce.soap.enterprise.sobject.Requirement__c;
import com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException;
import com.sforce.ws.ConnectorConfig;
```

Can anyone help me with a solution? Great thanks

Comment: You mismatched the connector and the sObject that you're using. You need to make sure you're importing the right objects in your source. Unfortunately, given the limited amount of code you provided, we cannot provide a full answer other than "check your work." If you want more help, you can [edit] your question to include additional code.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. I edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code,

```
SaveResult[] results = connection.update(new Requirement__c[] {updateRequirement});
```

Notice that instead of generic SObject, I am using the array of `Requirement__c`

Comment: Thanks a lot. it's working now

Comment: @Test please mark the answer as answered so it helps anyone that comes here to know it was right answer